# Background image to show on hover - list item

Tags: html, css, background, hover, html-lists

Attempting to get a background image to show only on hover of a list item. Currently at this:

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">WHO ARE WE?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WHAT WE DO?</a></li>
            <li>GALLERY</li>
            <li>CALENDAR</li>
            <li>HISTORY</li>
            <li>CONTACT US</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

With this:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

li:hover {
    background: url('images/arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Having no luck so far. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Image is 300x205 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Can you give me a absolute path of the image (like this `http://example.com/image.png`)

Comment: this is working for me. Here's a jsfiddle with a different image

http://jsfiddle.net/ybmP5/

Comment: Sure: http://offer.vpn.sh/lsumc/images/arrow.png

^ Ignore the large amounts of space. I tried with the images in Peter Klipfel's post and still having no luck. Full URL at the moment is: http://offer.vpn.sh/lsumc/ if you'd like to see full source.

Comment: For the sake of UX, don't call images on hover, preload it!

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2603/

The issue is more likely the file path specified within the CSS to the background image. You may need to go up a folder level depending on where you have the images stored in comparison to where the CSS file is stored. eg:

`background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat;`